# Console application message does not show up

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Code is perfect and simple.. you know :D
but the editor is empty? Whats the matter?

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: try this : Debug.WriteLine("Hello World");

Comment: im just pressing f5 or f11

Comment: @Sorrow: *"pressing f5 or f11"* - From within Visual Studio?  And then what happens?  What does "the editor is empty" mean?

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight That does something different. It prints to the debug console, not the output window. But it might be what he's looking at.

Comment: Well it runs the code, the console appears but its black without hello world

Comment: Which IDE? Which OS? Which console?

Comment: I tryed to convert a bool to a string and nothing happend aswell, so i tryed a simple hello world output but well theres none...

Comment: Visual studio 2019 Community Version 4.8.04084

Comment: Try adding `Console.ReadLine();` after the write statement.

Comment: @PMF You're right. I was taking a guess that he was debugging his app and that's why he wasn't seeing it.

Comment: well with f11 theres still no message but f5 works now.

Comment: so thanks for that, but i still dont know why lul

Answer (score 0):

I first suggest you go to "Tools->Options->Debugging" and then make sure the checkbox at "Close the console when debug ends" (4th element from the bottom) is *not* checked. That will leave the console window open when the application exits.

Answer (score 0):

Try running with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd>.

This starts without the debugger and keeps the window open after the program ends.

I always set up a button for it each VS install, to make my life easier.

[image: scr]

and the results:

[image: scr2]